# vtkCellLocator with Overlapping Cells

Tags: python, vtk

I have an unstructured grid with a mix of 2d and 3d cells which can share points. I need to look up particular cells by location. Is there a clean way to force vtkCellLocator to ignore particular cells (such as by type) when searching? Here in the example, I would want the top selection to pick the HEX cell, not the QUAD.

```
import vtk

# Create points
points = vtk.vtkPoints()
points.SetNumberOfPoints(8)
points.SetPoint(0,[-.5,-.5,-.5])
points.SetPoint(1,[ .5,-.5,-.5])
points.SetPoint(2,[ .5, .5,-.5])
points.SetPoint(3,[-.5, .5,-.5])
points.SetPoint(4,[-.5,-.5, .5])
points.SetPoint(5,[ .5,-.5, .5])
points.SetPoint(6,[ .5, .5, .5])
points.SetPoint(7,[-.5, .5, .5])

# Create Unstructured Grid and add Cells 
ugrid = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGrid()
if vtk.VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 9:
    ugrid.Allocate(2)
else:
    ugrid.AllocateExact(2,8)
ugrid.InsertNextCell(vtk.VTK_QUAD,4,[4,5,6,7])
ugrid.InsertNextCell(vtk.VTK_HEXAHEDRON,8,[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
ugrid.SetPoints(points)

# Create a locator
locator = vtk.vtkCellLocator()
locator.SetDataSet(ugrid)
locator.BuildLocator()

# Pick a point at the top
quad_cell_id = locator.FindCell([0,0,.5])
quad_cell = ugrid.GetCell(quad_cell_id)

# Pick a point close to the top
hex_cell_id = locator.FindCell([0,0,.49])
hex_cell = ugrid.GetCell(hex_cell_id)
```

The only way I can think of doing this is to split the data into 2d and 3d unstructured grids and a have a merged grid for other operations, but this seems wasteful.

Comment: It appears that the function returns the first cell in the locator. If you first insert the hex then the quad it will return the hex first. So if you control insertion of cells then you have your solution.